# Jquery autosuggest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery.
I am using the below code for showing autosuggest in text box.

```
$().ready(function() {
    function formatItem(row) {
        return row[0] + " (<strong>id: " + row[1] + "</strong>)";
    }

    function formatResult(row) {
        return row[0].replace(/(<.+?>)/gi, '');
    }

    //$("#suggest1").autocomplete(cities);  

    $("#custName").autocomplete(arrNames, {
        multiple: false,
        minChars: 0,
        width: 190,
        matchContains: true,
        autoFill: false,
        mustMatch: true,
        max: 20,                
    }
});
});
```

My problem is I want to call a javascript function along with the index of `arrNames` as parameter when user select one name from autosuggest. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you do it (using jQuery ui autocomplete) :

```
$("#custName").autocomplete(
        source: arrNames,
        select: function (event, ui) {
           //Do stuff here
        }     
    }
```

From jqueryUI website :

> **Select**
>
> Triggered when an item is selected from the menu; ui.item refers to
>   the selected item. The default action of select is to replace the text
>   field's value with the value of the selected item. Canceling this
>   event prevents the value from being updated, but does not prevent the
>   menu from closing.

**EDIT :**

It seems you are using Autocomplete plugin from http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

This plugin is deprecated... You should use jQuery ui autocomplete : http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: $("#custName").autocomplete(arrNames, {
    multiple: false,
    minChars: 0,
    width: 190,         
     matchContains: true,
    autoFill: false,
    mustMatch: false,
    max: 20,
    select: function (event, ui) {
              alert('You selected: ' + ui.item );
           } 

 
   });                I did this but still alert is not opening